# mv files older than 8 days in ksh script

Tags: ksh, aix

need to create script in KSH to mv files to other directory in same server older than 8 days they all .CSV

Comment: Welcome to unix.SE. I suggest you take a look at the `find` command. You'll find many similar questions (with answers) here.

Comment: I tried this but is not doing anything       [code] find /tmp/sappodb/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec mv -v {} /tmp/sappodb1/ \;

Comment: That's pretty close. You would have moved all files under `/tmp/sappodb` that hadn't been modified in the last two days to `/tmp/sappodb1`. All you were missing was the `-name '*.CSV'` bit.

Comment: The asker is inconsistent with the comments given to the accepted answer and the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the "find" command work more efficiently to delete many files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152513/can-the-find-command-work-more-efficiently-to-delete-many-files)

Comment: See also [Auto-delete inactive files after *x*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196022/80216);  related: [List of Recently Modified Files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33850/80216).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**simply use -t (--target-directory) in the mv cmd like the folowing way :**

```
find csvdir -type f -name '*.CSV' -mtime +8 -exec mv -t 'otherdir/' {} \;
```

*this was my suggestion before i install ksh & test.*
     while [ $(ls folder/ | wc -l) -ge 8 ];
          do
            mv "$(ls -1t folder/*.csv | tail -1)" /otherdir/ ;
          done

### test

[image]

Comment: mmm I cant get it, lol seems legit that way, maybe I spell wrong my question, I just need to keep the last generated files and mv the others to other directory I dont wnat to delete them

Comment: then just change rm "$(ls -1t folder/* | tail -1)"; to mv "$(ls -1t folder/* | tail -1)" /otherdir/ ;

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  It doesn't find the files older than 8 days, it finds (and deletes, or moves) all but the 7 most recent files.  and it does it extremely inefficiently, rm-ing or mv-ing one file at a time.

Comment: i already said that :)

Comment: find folder -type f -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \; #this command didn't work for him and according to his needs he wanted to keep the newest 7 file

Comment: I have read the question and all the comments and can't see anywhere that he mentioned keeping the newest 7 files.

Comment: read again his commant on the question , and read what i wrote before giving mt suggestion

Comment: why don't you just put a good question insteed of emply talking , i'll be the first to vote ....?!

Comment: Thks for all your help guys, the issue is i need to move all the files to another dir but just need daily to keep 7 files (the most recent) all are in .csv format

Comment: you can use find in the other question , if not working for you then just use the loop i suggested , because it'll do the same according to your case (the second loop which contain ' mv "$(....)" otherdir/ ' ) ! who knows maybe find itself uses 'while/do' !!!

Answer (score 0):

The command you tried was almost right, but use `+8` as the `-mtime` argument rather than `+2`.

You say you're using AIX so I'm going to guess that you're also using some ancient shell that requires `{}` to be quoted or escaped as `\{\}`.  See [gnu find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)

```
find /tmp/sappodb/ -type f -mtime +8 -exec mv -v `{}` /tmp/sappodb1/ \;
```

If you want to limit it to mv-ing .csv files only:

```
find /tmp/sappodb/ -type f -name '*.csv' -mtime +8 -exec mv -v `{}` /tmp/sappodb1/ \;
```